# CellEditEvent.getTablePosition.getRow() returns -1

Tags: javafx, javafx-2, tableview

I call `cellEditEvent.getTablePosition.getRow()` in an EventHandler. I apply this eventHandler to the `TableColumn.setOnEditCommit()` method. The `getRow()`-method always returns -1. Anyone an idea?

Looks like this:

```
colCtrNo.setOnEditCommit(new EventHandler<CellEditEvent<Foo, String>>() {
    @Override
    public void handle(CellEditEvent<Foo, String> t) {
        t.getTablePosition().getRow() // -1
    }
});
```

Comment: You have to provide the entire code. In my app getRow() returns the correct result.

Comment: I'm not allowed to put my development machine on the internet, so i can't copy the code. If I fire commitEdit in a KeyEvent it works, if I register an Event on the focusedProperty or textProperty, it will be -1....so strange!